# How Connect to remote host from Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ftp, aptana

I am using CODA from a long time .. now i use aptana studio 3

my Question

How Connect to remote host from Aptana Studio 3?

thanks

Answer (score 113, accepted):

From the Project Explorer, expand the project you want to hook up to a remote site (or just right click and create a new Web project that's empty if you just want to explore a remote site from there). There's a "Connections" node, right click it and select "Add New connection...". A dialog will appear, at bottom you can select the destination as Remote and then click the "New..." button. There you can set up an FTP/FTPS/SFTP connection.

That's how you set up a connection that's tied to a project, typically for upload/download/sync between it and a project.

You can also do Window > Show View > Remote. From that view, you can click the globe icon in the upper right to add connections and in this view you can just browse your remote connections.

Comment: thanks, but do I need to click sync everytime? is there an option to auto sync?

Comment: There are commands for invoking Synchronize, but no default keybindings. Go to Preferences > Keys and you can set up a keybinding shortcut to invoke one of the Synchronize commands. There's also commands for upload/download of individual files bound to Ctrl+Shift+U and Ctrl+Shift+U.
If you're looking for it to automatically perform uploads as you edit - or to run sync with some presets periodically, I think that's another issue and you will have to open a ticket asking for something like that: http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Comment: I dont see it in my Aptana... Is a plugin necessary?

Comment: @Christopher Williams, when trying to make above mentioned settings, it is giving this error under FTP connection section - "establishing ftp connection failed connection: refused connection"

Answer (score 33):

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Studio/Remote

(Drag this tabbed window wherever)

Click the add FTP button (see below); #profit

[image: Add New FTP Site...]

Answer (score 26):

There's also an option to Auto Sync built-in in Aptana.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

Comment: it is giving this error when trying to make above mentioned settings under FTP connection section - "establishing ftp connection failed connection: refused connection"... can you please help me to resolve it?