# save files locally and remotely

Tags: ftp

I searched for an answer but my files don't seem to save locally and remotely. I imported a project from my pc (local) and I set up an ftp connection (remotely) to my site. I was able to download and upload files to the server but they did not save locally? I did select sync in both directories. 
Basically what I'd like to do is develop WordPress sites both locally (using XAMP) and remotely - uploading saved files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a functionality within editors to save files locally as well as on remote location through ftp. What about your editor?

Comment: That would help (sorry). I'm using Aptana Studio 3

Comment: Although I haven't used Aptana but I have seen facility of remote connection in Dreemweaver, Eclipse and Netbeans. I think there will be some option for remote connection within  Aptana.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201939/how-connect-to-remote-host-from-aptana-studio-3

Comment: Thank you. I did do that but I don't see the changes locally. I must be doing something wrong