# How can i import remote project from ssh in Aptana

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, aptana

I have an amazon EC2 instance and I know how to access it with cygwin or putty

```
ssh -i pem_file.pem ubuntu@remote_ip
```

There is a project folder on it that I want, but I don't want to code in this env using vim or other plain editors. I want to import this project to my Aptana IDE for convenience. I found out that Aptana has a remote show view with two options: s3site or ftpsite.

Is this what I need to do?

If it is, can anybody tell me how to import it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, read the documentation and at least try something before asking random strangers for their help.

Comment: well i'm keep doing the "at least" for the last 2hours....thanks for the great advice

Comment: This will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201939/how-connect-to-remote-host-from-aptana-studio-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import, you can scp the folder in your local m/c

```
  scp -r -i path-to-secret-key ubuntu@ec2-address:/home/ubuntu/app-folder-location /home/user/local-mc-location
```